# setlocale php function returns false even if the locale is available in the platform

Tags: php, apache, setlocale

I am working on a cloud platform and the server is Apache.

In one of the site instances,the php script 
     **setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_GB.utf8"); always returns false.**

This locale,"en_GB.utf8" can be found available in the platform when I execute locale -a.
       Also noticed that , **setlocale(LC_ALL, 0); returns "C".**

Here PHP/Apache seems to be unaware about the underlying platform locales. Can anybody suggest me what could be wrong in case?

Answer (score 2):

before trying for `LC_ALL`, try `LC_TIME`.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_GB.utf8")
```

See if it helps...

Answer (score 2):

You have to reload the apache config in order for php/setlocale to recognize the new locale.

I had the very same problem (locale was installed and available on the platform) but `setlocale` did return `false` until I reloaded the apache config with `service apache2 reload`.

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL)
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_GB.UTF-8")
```

... did it for me.