# php setLocale fails, but that locale is installed on my server

Tags: php, debian, locale, setlocale

I have these 3 locales installed and generated in my debian VPS

[image]

Generating locales is doing this

[image]

> About webserver, I am using Apache with php-fpm

In my code i do this

```
echo "\n<!-- locale:\n" ;
var_dump($locale);
echo "  -->\n";
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");

$_dbg_set_locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
echo "\n<!-- esit setLocale:\n" ;
var_dump($_dbg_set_locale);
echo "  -->\n";
```

And I got that result

```
<!-- locale:
string(5) "en_GB"
  -->

<!-- esit setLocale:
bool(false)
  -->
```

As you can see `setLocale` is failing, returning a boolean `false`

why `setLocale` is faling?

Comment: Did you restart the webserver process after having these locales installed?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951974/setlocale-php-function-returns-false-even-if-the-locale-is-available-in-the-plat helps?

Comment: @NicoHaase: no, restarting the webserve is ininfluent [apache in my case,], but It worked restarting the php7.4-fpm-service [because I'm using apache + php fpm service in this vps] Thanks !!!

Comment: @NicoHaase: the linked question is not suggesting restarting of php-fpm so I say "no, it doesn't help"

Comment: In that case, you should add an Answer here for future readers, to show what _did_ help in your specific case. And you should edit your question to clarify the circumstances (e.g. use of php-fpm etc). Comments are not searchable, as I'm sure you know :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments, I was simply missing to restart services.

To be precise: because I'm using apache with php-fpm, I must restart *ONLY* php-fpm because all is related only to php-fpm

> Important side note: if you, future googler, are using apache with mod-php, I'm pretty sure this is not enough. Other questions/answers points to need to change something into apache configs and then restart apache2 (of course because there is not php-fpm at all)